# How to distort text to make it look like it's lying down?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I'm trying to study how the image below was done. The text in black is mine. I was able to more or less match the style of "DELIVERS" by using the shear tool, but to do the same in "WORKFLOWS" I need some other tool.

I've tried transforming the text to outlines and using the free transform tool (click, then press cmd), but that only moves one of the corners, and I was wondering if there was a better way (preferably that doesn't require making outlines)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this with the extrude effect. This has the advantage of staying editable, altough every time you update the symbols you need to openn and close the effect options for it to notice the dependency change.

So what you do is draw your text as vertical strips. Then make each strip a separate symbol by dragging each seoparately to symbol palette.

[image]

**Image 1**: Text Strips for your graphic

Then you extrude a white shape that has a face for every strip you intend to use. Set the shading to none and press map art.

[image]

**Image 2**: Extrude

Select the appropriate face and start mapping your symbols to the sides. Dont worry you can edit the symbols or sape postions later.

[image]

**Image 3**: Map artwork to faces of your base shape.

Adjust.

[image]

**Image 4**: After final adjustments

Comment: Can you get to the more extreme angle and perspective in the demo image of the OP with this technique?

Comment: @Confused you could be arbitrarily extreme, unortunately i threw away the sources.

Comment: as a whole, or does each part need to be rotated one by one?

Comment: @Confused its one piece.

Comment: Does that one piece have the ability to be rotated in any way you see fit? Like moving a camera around it? Or do you need to rebuild? I've never used the extrude features of AI or PS.

Comment: @Confused yes it does.

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator has a neat tool called the Perspective Grid that allows you to create a 3 point perspective horizon and place elements such as shapes and type. [The following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0oAgEkzwHU) gives a brief overview on this function - good luck with your project.

Comment: You just have to keep in mind that your text will be converted to a vector while using the "Perspective grid". So be sure your text won't change anymore before placing them in the "Perspective grid".

Comment: Also you can not have rotated perpective grids.

Answer (score -3):

This looks like it was done in After Effects, to me. Or a similarly capable 2.5D or 3D app.

*Here's an example of it done in AE:*
[image]

I don't know anyone that would enjoy attempting to do this in Illustrator with its quirky (at best) perspective grids. You'd need several grids to attempt this, and be fighting with them to get it "just so".

If you have an Adobe subscription that includes After Effects, it has a 2.5D layout with planes and cameras that makes this much easier (after some initial learning) than doing this in Illustrator. AE has one huge advantage: once setup, you can move the camera and frame your work easily, as you please.

---

In After Effects:

Because you're only dealing with two angles, flat and standing up, that's all that's required in terms of rotation in After Effects. "ChartMaxx" and "of WORKFLOWS" need to be laid over, rotated around their X axis so they lay flat, a 90 degree flop. They're at different Y heights. The others are all in their original positions in terms of rotation, none required.

Then a camera is moved to get this framing and perspective of the "scene".

The downside of After Effects is that this is all bitmaps... no vector output. The upside is that everything will remain editable, and animatable.

Comment: Thanks, this was useful, even if not for Illustrator. I don't agree with the negative votes

Comment: I think they're voting in the direction of the laying over text rotation, a negative 90 degrees ;)

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because of some misinformation: you don't need grids to do that in Illustrator; there are plenty reasons why do it there; that's not exactly what the OP asked for.